# Android studio slow over remote desktop

Tags: android, android-studio

Usually I develop on a box which has Android Studio installed locally, but there are times when I would like to remote in and develop over an RDP connection. However, whenever I do this, Android studio becomes unresponsive. Each keystroke has about a 10 second or more delay. It's worse when I am editing a UI file with the preview open. When I got back to my dev machine and logged in (with android studio still running from before), Android Studio ran just fine.

I know that applications using graphic hardware acceleration sometimes do this over RDP because of the way RDP draws. Are there some settings that I can tweak in Android Studio to get better performance over RDP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helped me is

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=off
-Dswing.aatext=false
```

You may want to do that also

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Use default anti-aliasing in system, i.e. override value of "Settings|Editor|Appearance|Use anti-aliased font"
# option. May be useful when using Windows Remote Desktop Connection for instance.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
idea.use.default.antialiasing.in.editor=false
```

Comment: Setting `sun.java2d.d3d=true` in the `idea.properties` file also improves speed.

Comment: It's not clear where to make this settings to someone not already familiar with those settings.